# user cannot change the checkstate of checkboxes. C# - windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I want to check if a checkbox is checked. therefore I use this code:

```
if (form.dynamic_checkbox.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello");
            number += 1;
            totalchecked += 1;
```

where as form is:`

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
```

then when I check the checkbox the message box doesn't show up. but when I check the checkbox state in codes with:

```
form.dynamic_checkbox.Checked = true;
```

and then the code works and I see the message box. this is bugging me and I need help. I created the checkbox manually form the toolbar.
Thanks.

C# - windows forms - .net framework

Comment: FYI, when you call _new Form1()_ you are creating a new instance of that form class. This instance is not the same instance already shown on your screen. This new instance has its own controls and using that variable you change the checkbox state on an instance that is not shown on your screen

Comment: thanks a lot. but when I create an instance of the form after user checking checkboxes. it doesn't work still. thanks again.

Comment: @pooyanami: Using checkbox.Checked is always hazardous because the value of a checkbox can be true, false and **null** too! So make sure to use checkbox.Checked==true. Sometimes it could be the problem too.